# escapeEcmaScript percantage special char

Tags: javascript, android

I use custom javascript bridge in android application,

I have a code in my bridge library project you can see below, this code escapes the string i gave

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    // responsdata comes from application layer
    jsonStr = m.writeValueAsString(responseData);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(jsonStr);
respondRequest = String.format("javascript:myalias.respond(%d, %d,\"%s\")", invocationId, responseStatus, escaped);

webview.loadUrl(respondRequest);
```

the problem is : when i inspect this data on client, there are some special characters which json parser doent recognise

some part of lines in data :

```
when debug application i can see like that after escape,

    1 - <td>%12,17</td></tr>\r\n<tr><td>

    2 - <td>%11,74</td></tr></tbody></table>\r\n<p class=

    3 -  %15 indirim!!","Url

    4 -  %15 fırsatı sizi bekliyor." 



    but after webview unescape data 

    1 - <td>,17</td></tr>\r\n<tr><td>

    2 - <td>,74</td></tr></tbody></table>\r\n<p class=

    3 -   indirim!!","Url

    4 -   fırsatı sizi bekliyor."
```

it puts somespecial char for %nn (%two digit numbers)

but below lines stays normal on both side

```
<td>%0,94</td>\r\n<td>954 TL</td>\r\n<td>2.465 TL</td>\r\n<td>%1,01</td>\r\n
```

How can i solve this problem ? are there any other library for escaping string ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug-->](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36995865) , and not yet fixed, this problem has came with android 4.4 's new webview,

but i worked around this problem this way:

```
respondRequest = String.format("javascript:mostar.respond(%d, %d,\"%s\")", invocationId, responseStatus,URLEncoder.encode(StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(jsonStr)));
```

Answer (score 0):

\r\n characters in JavaScript syntax 'is a suitable definition of the new line.

HTML language

```
<textarea> </textarea>
```

is used in.

html language line '\ n' instead of to

```
<br/>
```

income.

or for each item

```
<p> text </p>
```

If you write with a new paragraph is written with.

Comment: I think there are problem with only %twodigit number, it looks like encoding problem.